# Regex pattern in vbscript to match Text with multiple line

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a long string with Slno. in it. I want to split the sentence from the string with Slno.

Sample text:

```
1. Able to click new button and proceed to ONB-002 dialogue.
2. - Partner connection name **(text field empty)(MANDATORY)**
- GS1 company prefix  **(text field empty)(MANDATORY)**
```

I tried using vbscript regex to match a pattern. but it is matches only the first line of the string (1. text) not the second one.

```
^\d+\.\s(-?).*[\r\n].[\r\n\*+]*.*|^\d+\.\s(-?).*[\r\n]
```

And while splitting the string, for the Slno. 2 i want o get the below sentence as well. which am finding difficulty in getting.

Please assist me.

```
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 With regex
   .Pattern = "^\d+\.\s(-?).*[\r\n].[\r\n\*+]*.*|^\d+\.\s(-?).*[\r\n]"
   .Global = True
 End With
Set matches = regex.Execute(txt)
```

My Expectation is am looking for a regex pattern that match

```
1. Able to click new button and proceed to ONB-002 dialogue.

& 

2. - Partner connection name **(text field empty)(MANDATORY)**
- GS1 company prefix  **(text field empty)(MANDATORY)**
```

as separate sentence or group.

Comment: What is "Slno."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, to get the 2 separate parts including the line after you could use:

```
^\d+\..*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+\.).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits followed by a dot
- `.*` Match any character except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!\d+\.).*` Match a newline and use a negative lookahead to asset what is on the right is not 1+ digits followed by a dot
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMr3yv/1)